# SQL query to select from two fairly large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :
1) user where credentials of users are stored. It holds more than 1000 user records.

> ID | NAME | PASSWORD | USERTYPEID

2) user_logs in which the login details are captured. Its fairly large i.e. more than 100000 records.

> ID | NAME | DATEOFLOGIN | USERID | LOGINTYPE

I have to find the users which do not access the system between two given dates and their last logged in date.

```
SELECT MAX(userlogs.dateoflogin) AS lastlogindate,
       u1.id AS Id,
       u1.name AS Name
FROM USER u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_logs userlogs ON u1.id = userlogs.userid
WHERE u1.id NOT IN
    ( SELECT userid
     FROM user_logs userlogs2
     WHERE userlogs2.logtype='Login'
       AND userlogs2.dateoflogin BETWEEN '2013-05-10' AND '2013-05-20'
       AND userlogs2.userid IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY u1.id;
```

If the tables hold smaller records then it works well.
But in live system where user table has more than 1000 records and user_logs table has more than 100000 records, the query took very long time and I dont know it succeeded or not. :)

How do I optimize the above query. This query also finds the user who never attempt to login.

Comment: Do you have an index on `dateoflogin`?

Comment: yes its indexed on dateoflogin and userid

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to modify that subquery if you want to improve performance. They are convenient but they have a tendency to significantly slow down a query.

Secondly, make sure you have indexes on all the columns in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to your query, but a `LEFT JOIN` with a `NULL` check is often more efficient than `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT MAX(userlogs.dateoflogin) as lastlogindate , u1.id as Id , u1.name as Name
FROM user  u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_logs userlogs ON u1.id = userlogs.userid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT distinct userid
                 FROM user_logs  
                 WHERE logtype='Login' 
                 AND dateoflogin BETWEEN '2013-05-10' AND '2013-05-20' 
                 AND userid IS NOT null) userlogs2 ON u1.id = userlogs2.userid
WHERE userlogs2.userid IS NULL
GROUP BY u1.id
```

Make sure you have an index on `dateoflogin` so the subquery will perform well.

Compare the output of `EXPLAIN` with both queries.

Comment: Yeah the query looks fine but still its taking long time, its taking more 10 mins and running. I have not seen the result yet. Cant we achieve the same result using JOINs without using the subquery. Please be aware that user_logs has more than 100000 records, it also stores logout records.

Comment: the query you have provided took  1159477 ms (19 mins approx)  for 1058920 user_logs  and 29126 users. Is it efficient? or do we have other option to optimize the query.

Comment: How long does `select count(*) from user_logs WHERE logtype='Login' 
                 AND dateoflogin BETWEEN '2013-05-10' AND '2013-05-20' 
                 AND userid IS NOT null` take?